# Serialize the models to make them correspond to a json data format

Tags: json, django, api, rest, serialization

I have three models:

```
class GWS(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    rssi = models.FloatField()
    snr = models.FloatField()

class Data(models.Model):
    gwid = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    rssi = models.FloatField()
    snr = models.FloatField()
    freq = models.FloatField()
    dr = models.IntegerField()
    adr = models.BooleanField()
    classe = models.CharField(max_length=2,verbose_name="class")
    fCnt = models.IntegerField()
    fPor = models.IntegerField()
    confirmed = models.BooleanField()
    data = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gws = models.ManyToManyField(GWS,related_name="donnees")

class DataUplink(models.Model):
    appID = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    time = models.IntegerField()
    data = models.ForeignKey(Data,on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

The following json format represents the data of the DataUplink model sent from a third party application.

```
{
  "devEUI": "8cf9572000023509",
  "appID": 1,
  "type": "uplink",
  "time": 1629378939869,
  "data": {
    "gwid": "b827ebfffebce2d3",
    "rssi": -77,
    "snr": 10,
    "freq": 868.1,
    "dr": 5,
    "adr": true,
    "class": "C",
    "fCnt": 852,
    "fPort": 8,
    "confirmed": false,
    "data": "AgUCIzYBAIERAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADHDgA=",
    "gws": [
      {
        "id": "b827ebfffebce2d3",
        "rssi": -77,
        "snr": 10
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am writing an api which must retrieve this data in json via a post request and save it in the database. My question is how do I serialize my models?
below what i did but that doesn't work:

```
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = '__all__'

class UplinkSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Uplink
        fields = '__all__'

class GWSSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = GWS
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: depends what you want to do with the data like, you've already got the dict so just use that? If you need to save it to db then build models

Comment: Is it not possible to save the data as dict in a django model field?

Comment: I don't think so, but you also can't store a dictionary elegantly really especially if you want to store the data in the db. So a model(s) would be neccessary